# No text selection in input box inside anchor in Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, textselection

If a text input tag is placed inside an anchor, then in Firefox (on Windows) it is not possible to manipulate text inside the text box — text cursor doesn't change its position, and it is not possible to select the text. In Chrome you can change cursor position, but not select the text.

In some cases we can set the parent to be something else than anchor, yet is there a way to avoid this behaviour in general?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<p>No text select in FF:</p>
<a href="#">
   <input type="text" value="7777" />
</a>

<p>Working text select in FF:</p>
<span>
   <input type="text" value="8888" />
</span>
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPC42/WXLuy/3/).

Comment: HTML forbids nesting interactive elements. If you have an input inside an anchor then you do not have HTML. Breakage should be expected.

Comment: I totally agree, and I don't like this one bit — yet when combining 3rd party controls such situation may arise (in fact, it has, in my case), so I wonder if it is possible to affect this behaviour somehow, perhaps the community could help find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the href attribute when the input element is focused. As long as there is no href attribute, you will be able to select text inside the input field (tested in safari, chrome and firefox).

```
<a href="http://www.google.de" id="link">
  link
  <input type="text" id="input">
</a>

(function () {
  var link = document.getElementById('link');
  var input = document.getElementById('input');

  var saveHref = null;

  input.addEventListener('focusin', function () {
      savedHref = link.href;
      link.removeAttribute('href');
  });

  input.addEventListener('focusout', function () {
      link.href = savedHref;
      savedHref = null;
  });

})();
```

Working example: 
http://codepen.io/jjd/pen/JYwLVr

Comment: This is an interesting solution to a tricky problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

its because of the implementation error in browser.

actualy when we clicking browser it will look for the type of object
in this way 
    1.is this a link
    2.is this any other type( input area,image,

why it first checking for type "link"

```
 because clickig is firstly implemented for opening links,   
 anf its main usage is for open links
```

it detect first it as a link then it will call the

.     openlink(example)  function